# Defining a command to close and open environment

Tags: beamer, macros, environments

While preparing my lectures with beamer, I often find myself having to split a frame into two different ones. 
For instance, a first version of my slides contains:

```
\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{Theorem}
    Blah, blah, blah
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}{Corollary}
    Etc, etc, etc
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
```

When I complete my slides and add the proofs to these results, I must split it into two different frames

```
\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{Theorem}
    Blah, blah, blah
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}{Proof}
    Blah, blah, blah
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{Corollary}
    Etc, etc, etc
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}{Proof}
    Etc, etc, etc
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
```

I think that it would be very helpful I if could simply define a command to close and then open the frame environment:

```
\def\newframe{ \end{frame} \begin{frame} }

\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{Theorem}
    Blah, blah, blah
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}{Proof}
    Blah, blah, blah
  \end{block}

  \newframe

  \begin{block}{Corollary}
    Etc, etc, etc
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}{Proof}
    Etc, etc, etc
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
```

However, this approach does not work. Does anyone know if there is any way to define such a command?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `frame` is not really like normal LaTeX environments. Beamer determines the contents of a frame by finding what's between `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}`; with `\newframe` it wouldn't *see* the implied `\end{frame}`, which would show up only when `\newframe` is "executed" (and probably give errors).

Comment: `beamer` provides `\framebreak` in collaboration with the `allowframebreaks` option to the `frame` environment, but it breaks overlay support.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Unfortunately, I use tikz in my slides, and hence I have to make my frames `fragile`. This seems to break the `\framebreak` option... I'll close and open the environment manually.

Comment: Try if you can use a keyboard shortcut in your editor that inserts `\begin{frame} \end{frame}` for you (preferably with a line break inbetween). This way your code becomes clearer.

Comment: Thanks Hendrik, I can indeed make such a shortcut (I use emacs, so no problem about that), but I wanted a solution more TeXnical ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is *no* way to define a macro that issues `\end{frame}\begin{frame}` in `beamer`.

This is because `frame` is a very peculiar environment: when `beamer` finds `\begin{frame}` it looks for the next `\end{frame}` and stores in memory the entire contents *without* expanding macros; the macro expansion will take place later, when the frame contents will be processed. Such a way to proceed is necessary, because the contents needs to be processed many times, one for each slide in the frame.

Thus `\end{frame}` must appear *explicitly*, not hidden in a macro; if you use `\newframe` defined as

```
\def\newframe{ \end{frame} \begin{frame} }
```

the `\end{frame}` will appear when LaTeX is already processing a frame, where `\end{frame}` and `\begin{frame}` mean nothing: so an error will be raised.